# Can I set a conditional compilation constant in a web.config or app.config, if so how?

Tags: c#

I want to do [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) sort of thing.

Can I define my symbol (TESTING or DEBUG etc) in my app.config file?  If so can you provide an example of what the app.config would look like as I'm unsure where to start?

**Edit**: Added app.config to the title as I want to do this in an app.config

**Update**: It seems that I can only set conditional compilation constants at build time (web.config and app.config are used during runtime and only after the assembly has been compiled).  To set conditional compilation constants I need to do this in the csproj file or options in msbuild.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to ensure a portion of my code is not compiled unless I'm doing some unit testing (actually some integration testing).

Answer (score 4):

You can define preprocessor symbols in web.config like so (source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61ad1a74-ae76-47eb-86a9-1bf09f64c906/define-debug-constant-for-a-web-project )

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler
            language="c#;cs;csharp"
            extension=".cs"
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            compilerOptions="/d:DEBUG,MYCONST"/>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

See the `compilerOptions=""` attribute, that's where you can define additional symbols that you can use in your front-end `.aspx`, `.ascx` and `.master` files. I do not know if this works with Razor views or not. This approach also does not work for code-behind files which are compiled at design-time within the IDE, which have their own symbols.

Presumably this would also work for "code file"-type projects (i.e. "ASP.NET Websites") which do not use design-time compilation, but very few projects work on this basis anymore, so nevermind :)

Comment: I'm not using a web project, at the moment I'm just looking at a doing this in a c# library project and a app.config file.  At the moment I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: @TwistedInferno then why did you say `web.config` in your Q's title? In any event, compile-time symbols for class libraries are defined in the `.csproj` file, not `app.config` (which stores *runtime* configuration).

Comment: Yup, my bad, I was up late last night.  Thanks Dai

Answer (score 2):

No, the processor directives are not available in the web.config or app.config files.

Edited to add: These files are not actually compiled, and the #debug preprocessor value is used during compilation to tell the compiler what to do.

Comment: Thought this might be the case but Dai's answer suggests otherwise.  Do app.config files only work at runtime, how does this work in a web.config?

Comment: @TwistedInferno Dai's answer applies to web sites which compile the code behind files for aspx ascx when the website is requested that page.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with web application type projects.

The preprocessor defines in the app/web.config only affect code which is compiled after your website/application is running, but in the case of a web,console applications and libraries, all the code is compiled first and deployed as an assembly along with your static content and resources.

I would suggest instead creating an application setting and then doing a runtime check rather than a compile time check.  This would allow you to enable the settings in the app/web.config at runtime rather than requiring a recompile of your code in order to achieve the intended effect.